# get view ordering for a view using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, view

is there any way to fetch view order for a particular view using Rest api?

please help me with some sample code.

Comment: What do you mean by the view order ? In the order they are displayed or something else ?

Comment: it should be the field order in a view how can this be obtained using rest api

Answer (score 0):

By default the views are sorted in ascending order of their name. You can get all the views of a particular list using the below REST API

```
https://Your-site-url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list-name')/views
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below endpoint to get all the fields in a view and returned result of columns will already be in the order of fields selected in your view :

```
https://Your-site-url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/views('ViewGUID')/ViewFields
```

You can get the view GUID by following the below steps :

- Navigate to List Settings.
- Open the view.
- copy the URL and look for &View=
- Copy everything inside {} and paste it in place of ViewGUID in endpoint.

if URL is in encoded then you can decode it using the below URL :

[Decode URL](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Did you check it @pradeep?